# Order of install/uninstall of VS 2008 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I have VS 2008 Trial edition, SDK, and SQL Server 2008 currently.  But I need to uninstall VS 2008 Trial and replace it with VS 2008 Professional.  If I uninstall VS 2008 while keeping SQL Server 2008, then if I install VS 2008 Pro will SQL Server databases still be accessible from the new VS 2008 Pro?  And do I install the SDK after VS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers very specific [instructions](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/9/e/49eeb41a-a769-4520-80d6-671b8ae2bd06/SQLServer2008ReleaseNotes.htm) for this issue.

This is what worked for us:

1. Uninstall VS 2008 Trial
2. Uninstall SQL Server 2008
3. Install VS 2008 Professional
4. Install VS 2008 SP1
5. Install SQL Server 2008
6. Install SQL Server 2008 SP1

Answer (score 0):

> Will SQL still be accessible?

Yes, but only if you do the correct order of install.

> Do I install SDK after VS2008?

Correct, but it must be applied [after](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=21827&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True) the service pack.

`side-note:` From Windows 10 onwards SQL-2008 is [NOT supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562) (but does work).

---

This is the correct order of install for VS2008 with SQL 2008:

1. Option: Uninstall all packages (recommended).

   - Alternate: [Upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442563(v=vs.90).aspx) your install to pro.
2. Install **Visual Studio 2008 Pro** (if you didn't upgrade).
3. *If* you use **Team Explorer** install it now, [before SP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonba/2009/02/10/make-sure-you-reinstall-vs-2008-sp1-after-installing-team-explorer/)!!
4. Update VS2008 packages to [SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=10986) (always).
5. *If* you use the **SDK** you can [install](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=21827) install it now.
6. Run the SQL Server 2008 installer (always).
7. Update SQL Server 2008 **r2** [SP3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44271), *or* SQL Server 2008 SP4.
8. Install later cumulative updates to all products if required. [example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2673642)

Comment: Breakpoints:
- VS2008 needs to be Service Pack 1 to work with SDK or SQL 2008.
- any other VS2008 addons will revert it to before SP1 so do SP1 again after!