# installing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition, on my stand alone PC and I was reading [Order of install/uninstall of VS 2008 and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121945/order-of-install-uninstall-of-vs-2008-and-sql-server-2008). I am looking for confirmation. I have VS 2010 Express Edition installed which I would like to continue to use. Will I have to do any of the following steps before I install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.

1) Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition and/or

2) Uninstall VS 2010 Express Edition.

I have Windows 7 64bit professional.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter.

The issue with VS2008 and SQL Server 2008 (R2) is that SQL Server's Business Intelligence Development Studio is built using the VS2008 shell. You had to be careful with the installation order because the version with SQL Server had a service pack rolled in and that clashed with the regular VS installer; if you had already installed the VS2008 shell through SQL Server with SP1 rolled-in, you couldn't then install the VS development language plugins using the regular VS2008 install image.

However there's no clash between BIDS and VS2010. There's no reason you can't just install or upgrade SQL 2008R2 on your system as-is.